# convert html input array string into php array?

Tags: php, parsing, for-loop, input

In PHP, Is there and way or a loop to build an array from a string of varying size?

For example, I want to convert

```
$str1 = "page[1][name]";
$str2 = "content[1][language][2][name]";
```

expected output for str1:

```
$page = array
    1:
       name
```

expected output for str2:

```
$content = array
    1:
       language
             2:
                name
```

But I need it to be the same function that builds the array regardless of how many [] dimensions.

I was thinking something like this:

```
$tmp = explode("[", $str1);
$arr = (array)$tmp[0];
for ($i=0; $i<count($tmp)-1; $i++) {
    $arr[$i] = array();
        .....
        .....
}
```

but I'm kinda stuck there and I think it needs to be more of a recursive function method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your input looks much like a query string and if so you can parse it with [parse_str()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php).

Example:

```
$str1 = "page[1][name]";
$str2 = "content[1][language][2][name]";

parse_str($str1, $v);
print_r($v);

parse_str($str2, $v);
print_r($v);
```

Output is what you expect it to be:

```
Array
(
    [page] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] =>
                )
        )
)
Array
(
    [content] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [language] => Array
                        (
                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] =>
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```